# File title validation on the time of upload in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to create an aspx file where I will have a tab to upload a file in SharePoint Online library. On upload, I want to check whether the file title is having the correct format or not. If file is not having the right format, I have to request user to check for the format. So, can some one help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Sample regex for file type validation, hope it would help you.

```
// Get test values from the file input and text input page controls.
        var fileInput = jQuery('#getFile');
        var newName = jQuery('#displayName').val();

        var parts = fileInput[0].value.split('\\');
        var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];
        var fileRegex = new RegExp('\.[^.\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+$');
        var fileType = fileName.match(fileRegex)[0];
        //todo
```

You could use official demo to upload file(above test demo is based on official demo also).

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery#code-example-2-upload-a-file-in-the-same-domain-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery